# Twitch: Token invalid or missing required scope

Tags: php, api, oauth, twitch

I am using the Twitch api authorization flow but it keeps saying my access token is not correct when i try to retrieve a user.

The access token Twitch gave me after authorization is stored in the database, then i use cURL
to get the user and twitch give me this error:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","status":401,"message":"Token invalid or missing required scope"}
```

The access token is send as a header

```
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'Authorization: OAuth '.$token
));
```

I searched google for this issue but found nothing relavant, access_token do not expire for as i can tell, can someone please help with this?

```
  $crl = curl_init();    
  curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/user');     
  curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  if($token)
  {
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
             'Authorization: OAuth '.$token
        ));

  }
  $ret = curl_exec($crl);
  curl_close($crl);
```

I just found out that i can get the user object bu only if i am on the page where twitch redirects me with the "code=[code]", if try to stay on that page and make the cURL request it all works fine, but after i saved the access_token in the database and leave that page the access_token becomes invalid

Answer (score 0):

Can't you send the token as an URL parameter? Just to test that the token is not invalid.

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken?oauth_token=[access token]`

Comment: yes i tried but getting the same error thats why i tried the header

Comment: when i go to https://api.twitch.tv/kraken?oauth_token=[access token] it says:

    ["token"]=> array(2) { ["valid"]=> bool(false) ["authorization"]=> NULL }

Comment: The token you are using is not valid then (or out of scope). Make sure you follow the procedures defined [here](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md) to obtain a valid token.

Comment: I read the whole api, access_token becomes invalid when i leave the page where the code is send by twitch